# How to include script that includes jQuery without conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load an external application that contains **the complete jQuery 3.2.1 library** inside of it.  Because it is an externally hosted app, it's not realistic to modify the code.  However, when I add the script to my page, I end up with lots of errors due to conflicts with other scripts already loaded.  As an experiment, I've tried downloading the app and wrapping the contents in an anonymous function, thinking that this would keep the new version of jQuery scoped locally within the app but it didn't make any difference.

Is there a simple way to include this app without modfying it's contents or relying on `jQuery.noConflict()` which would require many changes to my existing code?

Comment: How are you doing this loading ? And what in your code is conflicting?

Comment: The official docs suggest this: `(function() {
          var acc_script = document.createElement('script');
          acc_script.type = 'text/javascript';
          acc_script.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'example.com/app.js';
          var s = document.getElementById('acc_config');
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(acc_script, s);
        })();`  Tried that as well as `<script src="https://example.com/app.js" />`  Doesn't seem to matter

Comment: What is the application you're trying to load?

Comment: @KayakinKoder - It's a proprietary app. Can't disclose that here.  But I am happy to clarify the structure if there's something specific you'd like to know

Comment: It's basically the entire jquery library followed by some plugins and then the main application code all concatenated into a single file.  What I don't understand is why doesn't wrapping it in an anonymous function confine the newly loaded jquery code to the local scope

Comment: @billynoah jQuery is always exposed on global scope

Comment: @A.Wolff - ahh.. thanks.  didn't realize that.

Comment: What happens is their version overwrites the jQuery object you had and any plugins that were extended on it are gone

Comment: I wouldn't use their app given how poorly they implement something so basic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery.noConflict() in your code with limited changes by simply wrapping all of your code that uses jQuery in an IIFE and passing in the instance of jQuery you are using

try something like

```
<script src="path-to-your-jquery.js"></script>
<script>var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script>/* your plugins */</script>
<script>
    (function($){
       /* your code using `$` works fine here*/

    })($jQ);
</script>

<script> /* other app code */</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. - yes I understand - however, this is a huge sprawling ecommerce site with at least 20 other scripts being loaded.  Many of the errors are happening in other external script files which are expecting `$` to work and it's not realistic to wrap each and every one of them.

Comment: Only other suggestion is run that other app in an iframe. Also should report it as bug to not insulate their code using noConflict

Comment: Thanks - I 100% agree. An iframe is going to be really unpleasant for other reasons. I'm probably going to resort to hand editing their script using the method you outlined above and then syncing it regularly.  Appreciate the suggestion.